# How does one show that the zeta function for a finite field is rational?

Tags: finite-fields, riemann-zeta

I am asking about part (a) of Exercise 23, Chapter 5 in Serge Lang's *Algebra*. Let $k$ be a finite field of $q$ elements. The zeta function is defined to be
$$Z(t)=(1-t)^{-1}\prod_p(1-t^{\deg p})^{-1}$$
where $p$ ranges over all monic irreducible polynomials over $k$. Prove that $Z(t)$ is a rational function.

My attempts so far: Let $\psi(d)$ be the number of monic irreducible polynomials of degree $d$. Then for each $d$, there are $\psi(d)$ irreducible polynomials of degree $d$, i.e. $(1-t^d)^{-1}$ appears $\psi(d)$  times in the product. Hence
$$\prod_p(1-t^{\deg p})^{-1}=\prod_{d=1}^{\infty}(1-t^d)^{-\psi(d)}$$
But I can't seem to expand this product any further. Any help is appreciated. A hint is okay.

Comment: What is supposed to be the $(1-t)^{-1}$ factor ? From the unique factorization in $F_q[x]$ $$\prod_{p \ monic \ irreducbile \ \in F_q[x]} \frac1{1-t^{\deg p}} = \sum_{f \ monic \ \in F_q[x]} t^{\deg(f)} = \sum_{d=0}^\infty q^d t^d= \frac1{1-qt}$$

Comment: @renus I don't think that factor affects the result being rational or not so I left that out.

Comment: It affects your understanding of $\zeta$ functions. The main point is that the product over maximal ideals stays rational even for finite extensions of $F_q[x]$ lacking unique factorization. If we add a $(1-t)^{-1}$ factor it is for the maximal ideal $(x^{-1})$ of $F_q[x^{-1}]$ that we missed by looking only at $F_q[x]$, ie. the zeta function not of $Spec(F_q[x])$ (the coordinate ring underlying $\Bbb{A}^1_{F_q}$) but of $Spec(F_q[x]) \cup Spec(F_q[x^{-1}])$ (the coordinate rings underlying $\Bbb{P}^1_{F_q}$)